# Cloned copy of object is still referenced, arrays within becomes mutable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object which I would like to clone. I would like that the `questionsObj` always remains the same. In my project I build the `questionsObj` with a bunch of imports of arrays like this:

```
import teensJson from "../assets/teensJson"
import anotherJson from "../assets/anotherJson"
etc...
```

Which contains an array of strings, but for the sake of simplifying the code I'm giving you this snippet:

```js
const questionsObj = {
  teens: ["questionOne", "questionTwo", "questionThree"],
};

const shallowCopyQuestions = {
  ...questionsObj
}


const state = {};

["teens"].forEach(mode => {
  state[mode] = shallowCopyQuestions[mode];
});

console.log(questionsObj);

while (Object.values(state).some(arr => arr.length > 0)) {
  // Get a random mode that still has questions
  const modesWithQuestions = Object.keys(state).filter(
    mode => state[mode].length > 0
  );

  const randomMode =
    modesWithQuestions[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * modesWithQuestions.length)
    ];

  // Get a random question from the selected mode
  const modeQuestions = state[randomMode];
  const randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(
    Math.random() * modeQuestions.length
  );

  // Remove the selected question from the mode
  modeQuestions.splice(randomQuestionIndex, 1);
}

console.log(questionsObj);
```

After the second `console.log(questionsObj);` the `questionsObj.teens` now contains an empty array. I thought since I do `{...questionsObj}` I don't make a refrence to it anymore.

I have tried the old trick `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(questionsObj))` but doesn't work in the project (crashes), no reason why.

The line in specific which alters the strings inside of the array:

```
modeQuestions.splice(randomQuestionIndex, 1);
```

What am I doing wrong here, happy for any tips!

Comment: As the name says, you're making a shallow copy. You're copying the object backbone, you're not copying the array. You want a deep copy.

Comment: Since you put that in the variable name, I would think that you understand the difference between shallow and deep copies.

Comment: @Barmar doing JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(questionsObj)) instead of {...questionsObj} in this snippet gives the same output.

Comment: @AraMalki I just tried it and it worked as desired.

Comment: @kosh Copying the clone function still gives the same output.

Comment: ["teens"].forEach(mode => {
  state[mode] = [.... questionsObj[mode]];
});

This works.  @Barmar are you sure JSON.parse(...) works as you told?

Comment: When I changed to `const shallowCopyQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(questionsObj))` the output showed the original array twice.